# Window.ShowDialog failes on return

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

I have a custom input dialog box that request an user's name and a reson (because reasons) for doing a certain action in my application. The user clicks on a button on the main window and the dialog box shows, as it should.

The user then enters his/her name and the reason and clicks ok. The dialog then closes but I ( the program) never receives an answer. Here is my XAML for the input dialog:

```
<Window x:Class="Sequence_Application_2.GUI.ForcedRackInput"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Forcera Rack" Height="300" Width="300"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">


<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="274*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="OperatorNameText"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="15,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Namn:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Orsak:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0.5">
        <TextBox Name="ReasonText" Margin="15,98,15,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" />
    </Border>

    <Button Name="OkButton"    IsDefault="True" Content="OK" Click="OkButtonPressed"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26.202,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Name="CancelButton" IsCancel="True" Content="Avbryt" Margin="152.202,233,47,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the "behind code":

```
namespace Sequence_Application_2.GUI
{
using System.Windows;

public partial class ForcedRackInput : Window
{

    public string OperatorName { get { return OperatorNameText.Text; }  }
    public string ForcedRackReason { get { return ReasonText.Text; } }

    public ForcedRackInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OkButtonPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }


}
}
```

and this is how I call the code (from a model, not a "window class")

```
public void ForceClosingRack(Flow forcedFlow)
    {
        var forcedRackWindow = new ForcedRackInput();

        string operatorName = "";
        string reasonForForced = "";

        if( forcedRackWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            operatorName = forcedRackWindow.OperatorName;
            reasonForForced = forcedRackWindow.ForcedRackReason;

        }

    } // code jumps from "if(forcedRackWindow.... to this line when ok is clicked in the dialog
```

Looked for the solution for some time now and I just about to change career

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem doesn't lie in the code, which seems to be fine, but in your `if` statement.

When you run your program in `Debug` mode it should work as expected.

My guess is that you are assigning the variables `operatorName` and `reasonForForced` inside your `if` statment but they are not used anywhere else in the program and hence the whole `if` statement is ignored by the compiler and not present when running in `Release` mode.

A small modification in your code which embeds different behaviour depending on the variable values can prove my guess:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var forcedRackWindow = new ForcedWindow();

    string operatorName = "foo";
    string reasonForForced = "foo";

    if (forcedRackWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        operatorName = forcedRackWindow.OperatorName;
        reasonForForced = forcedRackWindow.ForcedRackReason;
    }

    if(!operatorName.Equals(reasonForForced))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("We are not the same");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's it! I changing career. I ran the program in release mode instead of in Debug mode when I was debugging.... Thanks. Sometimes, a couple of additional eyes is all you need! :-)

Thank you!